# How to find the next value in this case

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate, erp

So it's a bit complex.

We have a "report" in ERP system. It's like a big query from few tables... but, it's not so important, i guess. We have thousand of rows.

It's only an example:

[image]

How can I search for the "next flyer number" ? So if item is in flyer 2015C and 2016C I want to get "Extended flyer".

The logic here is: if the item is in actual flyer +1 = that's an "Extended flyer".

`2015C`**:** `20` actual year, `15` is number of the flyer. `C` is the type of the flyer.

The date is from year - 2008, to today. So I can't count only values (there are lot of items with lot of flyers).

Maybe something with `LAG/LEAD` ?

Now I'm using this query, but it's not accurate (self join):

```
decode(null,
  (select count(*) 
   from --my_actual_table g
   where g.id = id 
   and g.place_of_delivery = place_of_delivery 
   and g.partner = partner
   and g.date <= date and g.date >= date-22 
   group by g.id, g.place_of_delivery, g.partner 
   having count(*) > 1 ),
null,'Extended flyer')
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Instead of picture, provide actual data as create and insert statements for sample data. And clearly show the desired output.

Comment: `2015C`: the lessons of history teach us that smart keys are dumb.

Comment: @APC so damn true

Comment: @APC I'm not sure, but i think the `2015C` is not primary key (in our system is not). It's like a plate number. Flyers are exported from another system in XMLs. Our key for this looks like this `036200002049` (another column, not listed here). I just wondering, if is it not possible to `sbstr(flyer,3,2)` and somehow `lag/lead` it to extracted +1 ->16. Silly, but  i dont have another idea.

Comment: @Know-nothing . . . Does something in your table represent an "item"?  I'm also a little lost on what you mean by "next flyer number"?  Is that by some sort of incrementing?  Or based on time?  Or based on something else?

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok, let's simplify things a bit. It's a delivery "report". On the jpg we can see which `items` = `id` + `name`, were ordered & delivered. Date is the delivery date. Hard to explain, but we have flyers (stock price) biweekly. It may happen, that item is in 2 flyers, and we have overlap. Every flyer has start date & end date. Flyer's "number"(on jpg) are increased by 1. IF item is in 1 flyer..there is nothing to do. Item is in flyer eg:2015C and eg:2017C..there is nothing to do. BUT if it's in flyer eg:2015C and eg:2016C (=next one) i want an output: `Extended`.

Comment: @Know-nothing - `2015C ` is not the primary of this table but it should be the primary key of **some other table** albeit one which doesn't seem to exist in your system.

Comment: @Know-nothing there is something like LAG, and it might be working in this case i guess. Would you mind having additional column, or where would you like to have this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created some table, which consist of only one column: flyer.
And the query looks like:

```
Select flyer,
case when to_number(substr(flyer,3,2))-to_number(substr(previous_flyer,3,2))=1 then 'Extended' else ' ' end
from
(
 Select flyer, 
 LAG(flyer,1) over (order by flyer) as previous_flyer
 from stackoverflow_table
)
```

Checked that and its working, i get an output:

```
2015C    
2017C    
2018C   Extended
2019C   Extended
2021C    
2023C    
2024C   Extended
2025C   Extended
2027C    
2029C    
2030C   Extended
```